# Arrange the Divs that do not overlap

Tags: css

I have three divs in my form. One main div and two child divs (As one for left elements and another one for right elements). I have setted up everything fine. But when window resize, the two left and right divs are overlapping each other. Please suggest me any genuine way to do this ..

**View Code**

```
<div id="first" style="width: 100%;">
 <div class="divmain">
  <div class="divleft">
                <label class="label">
                    Invoice No.</label><span class="mand">*</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divright">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.No, new { @class = "txtbox" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.No)
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.divmain
{
padding: 15px;
width: auto;
position: relative;
height: auto !important;

}

.divmain .divleft
{

position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 1%;
bottom: 0;
height: auto;

}

.divmain .divright
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 16%;
}
```

[link for the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dheyvendaran/s4xtb/)

Even when window resize the divs should not overlap each other and should stay as like when window is maximized.

Comment: You could use display:block;
Oh and don't use position:absolute ..

Answer (score 0):

See the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sWmmv/1/) !

```
.divmain
{
padding: 15px;
width: auto;
position: relative;
height: auto !important;
background:#CCCCCC;
}

.divmain .divleft
{
float:left;
width:auto;
top: 0;
left: 1%;
bottom: 0;
height: auto;
display:block;
background:#CCCFFF;
}

.divmain .divright
{
float:left;
width:auto;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 16%;
display:block; 
background:#CCFFFF;
}
```

Comment: In the overall width of the main div as 100%. divright should be placed always 16% from divleft. In your demo divright is placed immediately after the divleft. pls see my edit